# Access violation using different c++ runtime build VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, signalr.client

I got an c0000005 memory exception when my program use a newer version of c++ runtime, specifically of msvcp140.dll :

- 14.16.27012.6 the program works
- 14.24.28127.4 the program crashes.

My application uses signalrclient library for connecting to our web service. When there’s a problem with the connection, the program crashes with an access violation. 
I got the stack from a dump:

```
00 0b7ff34c 0b7ff370 BC32RECV!__ExceptionPtr::_RethrowException+0x82 [d:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\crt\crtw32\eh\excptptr.cpp @ 541] 
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
01 0b7ff350 052b1466 0xb7ff370
02 0b7ff358 052b1561 BC32RECV!std::exception_ptr::_RethrowException+0x6 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\exception @ 282] 
03 0b7ff370 052b395b BC32RECV!std::rethrow_exception+0x31 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\exception @ 358] 
04 0b7ff388 052b3e8f BC32RECV!Concurrency::details::_ExceptionHolder::_RethrowUserException+0x2b [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\ppltasks.h @ 789] 
05 0b7ff3d8 052b9d09 BC32RECV!Concurrency::details::_Task_impl_base::_Wait+0x22f [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\ppltasks.h @ 1613] 
06 (Inline) -------- BC32RECV!Concurrency::task<unsigned char>::wait+0xf [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\ppltasks.h @ 3297] 
07 (Inline) -------- BC32RECV!Concurrency::task<void>::wait+0xf [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\ppltasks.h @ 4223] 
08 0b7ffa60 052c75e1 BC32RECV!try_connection+0x479 [c:\my .net projects\builder\main\utility\bc32recv\bc32recv.cpp @ 578]
```

The code of my function is :

```
try {

    client->connection.start().wait(); -> access vio
    connection_success = true;
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
...
}
```

It seems it had a different std::exception_ptr, changing version from 14.16.27012.6 to 14.24.28127.4 of msvcp140.dll.

I assumed compatibility was maintained in this case when only the build / minor version changes.

The exception info from the dump is:

```
0:014> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 052c7d2e (BC32RECV!__ExceptionPtr::_RethrowException+0x00000082)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: b0688e75
Attempt to read from address b0688e75
```

There's a attempt of reading b0688e75 address. 
The first frame of the stack reports:

```
frame 0n0;dv /t /v
00 0b7ff34c 0b7ff370 BC32RECV!__ExceptionPtr::_RethrowException+0x82 [d:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\crt\crtw32\eh\excptptr.cpp @ 541] 
@ebx              class __ExceptionPtr * this = 0x0a09b2bc
0b7ff2f8          struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD ThisException = struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD
@eax              struct _s_ThrowInfo * pThrow = 0xb0688e69
<unavailable>     struct _s_CatchableType * pType = <value unavailable>
<unavailable>     void * pExceptionBuffer = <value unavailable>
```

I dont know how to "read" theese infos. What it seems near to the address VAM is

```
@eax              struct _s_ThrowInfo * pThrow = 0xb0688e69
```

and it seems wrong:

```
((BC32RECV!_s_ThrowInfo *)0xffffffffb0688e69)                 : 0xffffffffb0688e69 [Type: _s_ThrowInfo *]
    [+0x000] attributes       : Unable to read memory at Address 0xffffffffb0688e69
    [+0x004] pmfnUnwind       : Unable to read memory at Address 0xffffffffb0688e6d
    [+0x008] pForwardCompat   : Unable to read memory at Address 0xffffffffb0688e71
    [+0x00c] pCatchableTypeArray : Unable to read memory at Address 0xffffffffb0688e75
```

Comment: The fact that a program appears to work properly does not mean that it is valid. You could still have some undefined behavior in your code that didn't result in a crash in `14.16.27012.6` , but might manifest as a crash in `14.24.28127.4`.

Comment: Your comment is clear. All the stack path is about Microsoft Concurrency runtime, code inside msvcp140. What do you suggest me to investigate to find the problem?

Comment: The problem with undefined behavior is, that the reason for that could be at any code that was executed earlier, so the place where your application crashes does not need to be invalid, it just crash because your application is already in an invalid state. E.g. dereferencing a pointer that is not initialized or not valid anymore, out of bound access to on a container like `std::vector`, or anything else that would result in UB.  Increasing the warning level and check and solve each warning could help, but not every possible action that could cause UB would lead to a warning.